# How to enable disk performance display in Windows 2019 task manager?

Tags: windows-server-2019, task-manager

On Windows server the disk performance is not displayed by default in Task Manager.

For Windows 2012R2 (and some other versions) it can be enabled by the command `diskperf -y` (and restarting Task Manager).

This does not work on Windows 2019. Is there another solution?

(all solutions on internet that I found are for older Windows server versions)

Comment: It works for me on server 2019, did you change any other settings on the server?

Comment: I checked again, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `diskperf -y` must be run as an Administrator.

Otherwise it wont work (but does not report any error, the output is the same as if it worked).

Also, Task Manager must be restarted if it is running when the above command is executed.